# Looping through pixels with Cython still slow

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I get no speed difference here between regular python code. It says the bottleneck is the last two lines of code in the html file. Is there any way around this?

What I am trying to do is loop through pixels and add coordinates where rgb value is below 210 to a list.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import time
import cython
import cv2

filename = "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Testing/files/file001.png"
image = Image.open(filename)
size = width, height = image.size
image_data = np.asarray(image)

cdef list list_text = []

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef get_image_data():
    cdef int y, x
    for y in range(1683):
        for x in range(1240):
            if image_data[y, x] < 210:
                list_text.append([x, y])
```

Comment: How can an RGB value be less than 210? Surely you need to check if R and G and B are less than 210? Or if one of them is less than 210? But in general, an RGB value will have 3 parts - R, G and B so you'll need to compare against a triplet like (210, 180, 100).

Comment: It is gray scale, so it only outputs one value.

Comment: If your image is greyscale, you will have a grey value not an RGB value! Why don't you use Numpy's `np.argwhere(image_data<210)` ?

Comment: Edit: I am an idiot, thanks a lot. It does seem to get coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The looping isn't any problem, but appending lists to lists is very slow. To avoid this you can either allocate an array large enough for the data and shrink it afterwards (or copy the data in an array which has the exact size you need) or you can implement your function using `std:vector`.

In this answer I use `Numba` because I'm not that experienced in performant Cython coding, but a Cython implementation should be straight forward. Numba has also a limited internal representation of list and tuples, but I don't know if the same is available within Cython.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def get_image_data_arr(image_data):
  array_text = np.empty((image_data.shape[0]*image_data.shape[1],2),dtype=np.int64)
  ii=0
  for y in range(image_data.shape[0]):
    for x in range(image_data.shape[1]):
      if image_data[y, x] < 210:
        array_text[ii,0]=x
        array_text[ii,1]=y
        ii+=1
  return array_text[:ii,:]

@nb.njit()
def get_image_data(image_data):
  list_text = []
  for y in range(image_data.shape[0]):
    for x in range(image_data.shape[1]):
      if image_data[y, x] < 210:
         #appending lists
         list_text.append([x, y])
         #appending tuples
         #list_text.append((x, y))
  return list_text
```

**Timings**

All timings are without compilation overhead (the first call to the function is excluded from the timings).

```
#Create some data
image_data=np.random.rand(1683*1240).reshape(1683,1240)*255
image_data=image_data.astype(np.uint8)


get_image_data (Pure Python)                   : 3.4s
get_image_data (naive Numba, appending lists)  : 1.1s
get_image_data (naive Numba, appending tuples) : 0.3s
get_image_data_arr:                            : 0.012s
np.argwhere(image_data<210)                    : 0.035s
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and it works. It seems only the first time will be slow. There is some syntax in there I need to get familiar with though. I got it down to .3s myself, but this is another 200x faster. And it seems less of a headache to use vs Cython. What are the limitations with regards to lists and tuples?

Comment: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html Same dtype of all list entries, only simple datatypes. But as mentioned in the answer avoid lists in any performance critical code. You can also use @nb.njit(cache=True) which avoids the recompilation on reopening the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Numpy's `argwhere()` function as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# Create a starting image
im = np.arange(0,255,16).reshape(4,4)
```

That looks like this:

```
array([[  0,  16,  32,  48],
       [ 64,  80,  96, 112],
       [128, 144, 160, 176],
       [192, 208, 224, 240]])
```

Now find coordinates of all elements less than 210:

```
np.argwhere(im<210)
```

That looks like this:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1]])
```

Comment: It does work for this case so I labeled it as the answer. But it seems if you want to do more complicated loops through your pixels (like stop when you find a pixel that is < 210 and start doing some sort of search operation on the surrounding unsearched pixels) you have to use python loops, and that will really slow things down again. 

For example if there is black text, and there are dark boxes with white text in it, I want to filter out the dark box, and save the white text as black text.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Questions (and answers) are free, so if you have a better example, maybe with a picture, of such a scenario, then ask again. There are some clever folk on here and we may all learn something! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I sort of fixed it. Now I got to figure out how to save those pixel coordinates to a two dimensional array. Since if I append python style it slows the whole thing down. Any suggestions? I also do not really want to return image_data again.

Btw it is interesting that this code is 28000x faster than python! I expected a 100x speed gain, not this much.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef const unsigned char[:, :] get_image_data(const unsigned char[:, :] image_data):

cdef int x, y
cdef list list_text = []

for y in range(1683):
    for x in range(1240):
        if image_data[y, x] < 210:
            pass
return image_data
```

Comment: Well, your code does nothing, right? It might be interesting to see how much of the code the compiler optimizes away.

Comment: Yeah I want to add those coordinates to a list, and return that list. The problem is, it will slow down the code. And I cannot return the list, since for some weird reason I get a value error if the function does not return a constant.