# How can I apply mpi4py to the following loop to speed it up?

Tags: python, mpi4py

In the past I have not needed to use parallel computing, because my python scripts aren't usually computationally intensive. Recently, I wrote the following for-loop and found that it takes on the order of 10 - 15 minutes to run:

```
cpx_var = np.linspace(0.20,0.80,301)
horn_var = np.linspace(0.20,0.80,301)
plag_var = np.linspace(0.05,0.1,26)
mag_var = np.linspace(0.02,0.06,21)
ap_var = np.linspace(0.002,0.006,3)

poss_comb = []
count=0

for i in cpx_var:
    for j in horn_var:
        for k in plag_var:
            for l in mag_var:
                for m in ap_var:
                    count = count+1
                    if abs((i+j+k+l+m)-1.0)<0.002:
                        poss_comb.append([i,j,k,l,m])
print(count)
```

I've been looking into mpi4py as a means to speed up my for-loop, but I am not sure how to apply it to my example. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Zack Eriksen

Answer (score 0):

Although multiprocessing is a way to speed up your code, the first thing you should try is to make your code more efficient in the first place. You are using 5 nested loops, which in Python, is crazy! As much as possible in Python you should aim to use arrays to implement code instead of for-loops.

Here is a solution where I only use one for loop at the very end (it is actually a list comprehension which is a slightly faster version of a for loop). I have used the np.mesh function and then some slicing to get rid of all of the loops you had and instead only have the list comprehension to put all the results into the list format you want.

So have a play with this version. It only takes about 20 seconds to run on my laptop

```
import numpy as np

cpx_var = np.linspace(0.20,0.80,301)
horn_var = np.linspace(0.20,0.80,301)
plag_var = np.linspace(0.05,0.1,26)
mag_var = np.linspace(0.02,0.06,21)
ap_var = np.linspace(0.002,0.006,3)

cpx_vars, horn_vars, plag_vars, mag_vars, ap_vars = np.meshgrid(cpx_var, horn_var, plag_var, mag_var, ap_var)

selection = abs((cpx_vars + horn_vars + plag_vars + mag_vars + ap_vars)-1.0)<0.002

poss_comb = [list(comb) for comb in zip(cpx_vars[selection], horn_vars[selection], plag_vars[selection], mag_vars[selection], ap_vars[selection])]
```

Comment: I'm sorry that this didn't answer your question about using mpi4py, but in reality this array-ified version of your code will run faster than your original loop would even if you used multiprocessing. So I think it better advice to you than to actually explain how to use mpi4py. (also note that numpy uses multiprocessing automatically in the background so you really are parallelising your code, just much more efficiently)

Comment: Great, thank you! I know it's good practice to avoid nested loops in python, but I wasn't really sure if there was a good way to use arrays instead. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to speed up your code by another 23 times. Since I answered this question I have been learning more about a Python package called `numba`. This package is really clever and it essentially translates your Python functions to machine code and can give you huge speed-ups (depending on what you are doing).

I was having a play around with this package and I thought of your question here, I wanted to see how fast numba could do it compared with using numpy arrays. Doing a comparison between your code, the numpy version I pasted in the answer above, and the numba optimised version of your code. I found that the numpy (no loop) version was 23 times faster than your loop version, but the numba version was 455 times faster!

Anyway I thought you might like to see this. The numba version is about 23 times faster than my answer above. Below are 3 versions of the code I was using. I made your code into a function called `original_loop_function`, the numpy version I posted above into the function `numpy_function` and the faster numba version of the code is the function `numba_loop_function`. Hopefully this is still useful to you

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

cpx_var = np.linspace(0.20,0.80,301)
horn_var = np.linspace(0.20,0.80,301)
plag_var = np.linspace(0.05,0.1,26)
mag_var = np.linspace(0.02,0.06,21)
ap_var = np.linspace(0.002,0.006,3)


def original_loop_function(cpx_var, horn_var, plag_var, mag_var, ap_var):
    '''Your original version of this code'''
    poss_comb = []
    count=0

    for i in cpx_var:
        for j in horn_var:
            for k in plag_var:
                for l in mag_var:
                    for m in ap_var:
                        count = count+1
                        if abs((i+j+k+l+m)-1.0)<0.002:
                            poss_comb.append([i,j,k,l,m])
    return poss_comb

def numpy_function(cpx_var, horn_var, plag_var, mag_var, ap_var):
    '''Numpy version of your code with no loops'''
    cpx_vars, horn_vars, plag_vars, mag_vars, ap_vars = np.meshgrid(cpx_var, horn_var, plag_var, mag_var, ap_var)

    selection = abs((cpx_vars + horn_vars + plag_vars + mag_vars + ap_vars)-1.0)<0.002

    poss_comb = [list(comb) for comb in zip(cpx_vars[selection], horn_vars[selection], plag_vars[selection], mag_vars[selection], ap_vars[selection])]

    return poss_comb


@jit(nopython=True)
def numba_loop_function(cpx_var, horn_var, plag_var, mag_var, ap_var):
    '''Numba optimised version of your code'''
    poss_comb = []
    count=0

    for i in cpx_var:
        for j in horn_var:
            for k in plag_var:
                for l in mag_var:
                    for m in ap_var:
                        count = count+1
                        if abs((i+j+k+l+m)-1.0)<0.002:
                            poss_comb.append([i,j,k,l,m])
    return poss_comb
```

Comment: Preallocating an array zo the max. size should be much faster than a list append. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53849290/4045774